# Protobuf-net enum serialization behaviour changed in ver. 2.3.0

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Any serialized object before 2.3.0 will not be correctly deserialized in 2.3.0 or later if it contains enum values and is using DataMember with InferTagFromNameDefault instead of ProtoMember.

```
[DataContract]
public class ClassWithEnum
{
    [DataMember]
    public MyEnum Enum { get; set; }
}

public enum MyEnum
{
    FirstValue,
    SecondValue
}
```

I have this class. Serializing it using this code.

```
{
    RuntimeTypeModel.Default.InferTagFromNameDefault = true;

    var v = new ClassWithEnum { Enum = MyEnum.SecondValue };

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
       Serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, v);
       var bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Before 2.3.0 this will result in a byte[] { 8, 2 }
and after 2.3.0 it will result in byte [] { 8, 1 }

Is there any way I can make later versions serialize the same way as the earlier ones?

Comment: Hmmm... you're right. This is the first time I've seen a report on this, but it definitely changed between 2.2.1 and 2.3.0, which is very... unfortunate. Trying to think about options here.... I take it that explicitly configuring your enums (in code or via attributes) isn't what you're looking for here?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a viable solution for me since the enum is already explicity configured and is used in other places where its not serialized. If I could just figure out a way to deserialize it like it did before I could resave/migrate all data. Im trying to avoid deploying a second program (running old protobuf) to do the migration. Any ideas?

Comment: when you say "is already explicitly configured", can I just clarify what you mean there? I'm talking about adding attributes to the enum, which doesn't affect any other code - it doesn't impact the raw C# values, for example. The main time this is problematic is if the place where the enum is defined: doesn't currently reference protobuf-net. It is also possible to configure the enum at runtime via the RuntimeTypeModel, which requires no changes to the enum itself - it just needs about 3 lines of code before you first serialize/deserialize. Are either of those viable? I can do examples

Comment: I meant that each enum value got a corresponding int (=1) which I cannot change. And if possible I would like to avoid putting attribute on the enum.
However configuring the enum via the RuntimeTypeModel sounds promising. Just to see if we are thinking about the same solution.. ->

Comment: At runtime I can add the [ProtoEnum] attribute to the enum values starting at 1 instead of 0 and then do the deserialization. At first glance / testing this seems to result in the wanted behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ... unanticipated. I don't yet understand what happened here, but you're right that there was a change. It looks like historically there was an offset of `1` on the enum values when using `InferTagFromNameDefault`, and the "enum passthru" check fails to account for this (with "enum passthru" now evaluating to `true` here, where it would have been `false` previously).

The following seems to fix this at runtime:

```cs
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(MyEnum), true).EnumPassthru = false;
```

or via attributes:

```cs
[ProtoContract(EnumPassthru = false)]
public enum MyEnum
{...}
```

I will investigate what happened here.

Comment: Ah great! With this I can at least get it to run as before and correct the stored serializations. Thanks a lot!